# angular ng-options not selected value not render

Tags: angularjs

I am creating select element and set the values with array
In my controller I set

```
$scope.numbers = _.range(20);
$scope.selectedNumber = 5;
```

and my html

```
    <select ng-model='selectedNumber' 
class='some-class' 
ng-options="item as item for item  in numbers" >
</select>
```

the css of the class is

```
.some-class{
   border:1px solid gray;
   border-radious:xxx;
   width:xxpx;
  heihgt:xxpx;
}
```

my problem is that the selected value does not rendered on page load
only after clicking inside the select element.
(also happens when I use ng-class instead of class).

if I remove the class then then it just renders fine.

(another quick question : why if I don't add ng-model the ng-options does not display any content

Comment: can you give me a console log of your $scope.numbers?

Comment: <ng-app><scope.$id=2><scope.$id=3><scope.$id=4><scope.$id=5> I am using ui-router and the controller is in a parent state (I moved the controller to the children view but same result

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared few examples for you that I hope will help you understand, I don't know what's your `$scope.numbers` type if it's an array of integers, strings, or objects but the `model` has to be the same type, and if you want model to be object then it has to be passed by reference. Although to answer your question `ng-model` is mandatory when `ng-options` are used, if you don't want model you can use this pattern

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{number}}</option>
</select>
```

And here are different input types for the select, please visit plunker to see it working

```
$scope.numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  $scope.selectedNumber = 5

  $scope.numbersTwo = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
  $scope.selectedNumberTwo = '6'

  $scope.numbersThree = [{
    num: 0
  }, {
    num: 1
  }, {
    num: 2
  }, {
    num: 3
  }, {
    num: 4
  }, {
    num: 5
  }, {
    num: 6
  }, {
    num: 7
  }, {
    num: 8
  }, {
    num: 9
  }, {
    num: 10
  }]

  $scope.selectedNumberThree = $scope.numbersThree[7]

  $scope.selectedNumberFour = 8
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7mzuj8Fg46xVv6bwhiOt?p=preview

Comment: first thanks. $scope.numbers are array of integers . (_.range(20) returns [0,1,2...20]) the problems starts when I am giving css to the select box I edited plunker and changed the css and that worked fine

Answer (score 1):

ng-options needs to be matching with ng-model in order to render the value.

For example if you ng-model is giving value of "Boston", you need to have that key/value pair or just the value in the object/array of your ng-options list. Its case sensitive as well.

Controller:

$scope.city = "Boston";
$scope.cityDetails = service.cityList;

Service:

$scope.cityList = {"Boston", "San Jose", "Chicago", "New York"};

so while trying to loop down, you need to loop in this way.

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-options="cityData for cityData in cityDetails"></select>
```